# Retrieve data from a another table and insert into a another

Tags: c#, mysql, vba, c#-4.0

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table according to the ID number and insert it to another table. The program is in C# and database in MySQL.

The retrieving table name is **student_dt** and the table name i want to insert is **student_att**

Here's what I'm doing so far

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert into student_att values(`id`, `nic`, `name`, `address`, `number`, `batch`)";
        string Query1 = "select * from student_dt where id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide all data");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");

            string Query = "select * from student_att ;";
            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
            MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dTable;

        }
```

Comment: First, read this: http://Bobby-tables.com and never again in your life (ever) use string concatenation to insert a user-provided value into a raw SQL command. There is never a need for it and it's among the number one ways to get hacked, fired or both

Comment: Second, there is no need to download the data at all. MySQL will be happy to run a query of the form `INSERT INTO t(a,b,c) SELECT x,y,z FROM u WHERE col=@val` To copy those 3 columns from U to T, for any row where COL is value @val

Answer (score 1):

You can do from one query

```
string query = "insert into student_att (`id`, `nic`, `name`, `address`, 
`number`, `batch`) select * from student_dt where id like '" + textBox1.Text + "%'"
```

Comment: No, don't perpetuate the problem of SQL Injection. Show the OP how to do it properly